# Updating existing table

Tags: powerquery

Is there any way how to update existing table in power query? I am loading data from two sources. One of the is excel table (lets call it arrData) and second source is some external workbook. I will join them in editor and I would like to replace original source (arrData) with the new table. Is there any way how to do it? I always get options to load it as a new table.

Comment: Update the SOURCE? Not the tool for that.

Comment: OK so source and target of the data has to be different?